# VSCODE Intellisense is not working. Using NVM

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

In TsServer Log encountering this error:

```
[20:0:44.403] NPM location: npm (explicit '--npmLocation' not  provided)
[20:0:44.404] validateDefaultNpmLocation: true
[20:0:44.404] Npm config file: /Users/<>/Library/Caches/typescript/3.5/package.json
[20:0:44.404] Updating types-registry npm package...
[20:0:44.405] Exec: npm install --ignore-scripts types-registry@latest
[20:0:44.417]     Failed. stdout:

    stderr:
    env: node: No such file or directory

[20:0:44.418] Updated types-registry npm package
```

I think because of deleting system node and using nvm tsserver is not getting the node path

Already set default nvm:

```
[127] % nvm ls
->     v10.16.0
        v12.5.0
default -> 10 (-> v10.16.0)
node -> stable (-> v12.5.0) (default)
stable -> 12.5 (-> v12.5.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/dubnium (-> v10.16.0)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.16.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.16.0
```

Set These settings in VSCODE:

```
{
    "typescript.tsserver.log": "verbose",
    "terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": []
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `typescript.npm` in VS Code to point to where your copy of npm installed?

Comment: Cool thanks. changing that solved it, `https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings`

Comment: Can you say more about what the path should look like like? I have set the path to the following, but it does not seem to solve the issue: C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/nvm/v10.23.0/npm.cmd